# Fixed buttons for accordion's content

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Scenario:

- I have an accordion.
- When it expands I have a form. Sometimes a long form (bigger than page height).
- The form action buttons are on the end of the form.

Problem:

- You must scroll the page to see/click on the action button. For some particular reason, the user may want to save it even without see all the form.

Question:

- How to fix the action button in the end of the screen?
- How to keep these buttons inside the accordion item (if you scroll to the end of the page, you should see other accordion item siblings)
- In other words: the action buttons should be attached to the end of the screen only while the end of that accordion item is not visible yet;

**Edit**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1vkcmo7a/1/

```
<div>
    <accordion close-others="true">
        <accordion-group heading="Item #{{i}}" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="a in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">long form</li>
            </ul>
            <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

Comment: show us your code?

Comment: Can you provide a code script that you are trying to achieve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

How about enclosing the accordion item contents in a div with fixed height and a scroll e.g.  `<div style="max-height:50px;height:50px; overflow:auto">` ?

See http://jsfiddle.net/1vkcmo7a/7/

Comment: It seems a relly good idea. But in this case, sometimes the action button will be hidden.